# Send button in yahoo mail page is not not visible - Firefox, Freebsd 7.2

Tags: python, firefox, freebsd, yahoo-mail

I have a python script that sends a mail from Yahoo including an attachment. This script runs on a Freebsd 7.2 client and uses firefox : Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; FreeBSD i386; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009072813 Firefox/3.0.10. The script fails with the error - Element xpath=//input[@value="Send"] not found. Checked the Page source, the x-Path exists. However, it is not visible in the compose page.

Kindly help me sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the button is inside an iframe. If it is then switch to frame and try it again.

Comment: Thanks Habeeb, However, I'm a novice with respect to these scenarios.. It's be great if you could explain a little. The button is found to be in <div class="contentbuttonbar hd"><div class="inner">... </div></div>

Comment: I have another idea. You can use Ctrl + Enter in ymail to send the email instead of clicking on the Send button. `send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)`